# insert "000088900" into SQLite,then query this data ,it's 889 ,how fix?

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I get some json for server ,and some data like "000089000","00098981000","00092823000"

When inserted into the SQLite, the data will be removed before and after the 0

is there a convenient way to fix that to get full text ?

Comment: Can you share the code how you _exactly_ create the table and insert the data?

Comment: change your column's data type to text from number.

Comment: o  yeah  after i check my code  ,i find out the data type is INTEGER ,thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's like when you're using Excel, if you're column (excel : the cell) is in number/integer type, you'll loose all the leading 0's. Consider changing your column type to Text